# Server Error 500 - Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, ubuntu-12.04, server-error

When I trying to install a new project, it shows "The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/psychicwiz/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.".
It cannot connect the mysql database. We use Ubuntu 12.04 and php 5.4 version. How to eliminate this  server error?. And to display the proper error rather than server error 500 ?

Comment: Error reporting on? -> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`. Also, check your logs, it should tell you why you're getting an Internal Server error. Then update your question with that information and people can help you better

Comment: have you set database credentials correctly?

Comment: okay. Let me check and update the question.

Comment: Cannot connect to the database.  I used a connect.php file, where it describe the database connection code in a class. But it doesn't enter the class. i am trying to echo something; but no result.

Comment: Please post your code in your original question, not as a comment

Comment: error log shows, undefined variable . when check it , its use keyword 'yield'. I have php 5.4 and the “yield” keyword is new in PHP 5.5. what to do ? Any solution?

Comment: You'd have to update your PHP version or modify your code to suit.

Comment: okay.. Thank you for your time